# How can I have my profile removed from Jobs and Developer Story?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I was ok using the "jobs" and "developer story" features to test them out. I don't want those anymore and I want to opt out.

This specifically means:

- I don't want to receive any mail about those anymore. I did most of it manually, but I have no way to know if I've done it entirely.
- I want my profile to be "unmatched" from everything. I did most of it manually, but I have no way to know if I've done it entirely.
- I don't want my data shared with other companies (Crunchbase with the Developer Story, for instance).
- I want to "see" that I need to opt-in to those features to access them again. I received a mail that said "You are receiving this email because you have a Stack Overflow CV. We’ve migrated your CV to your Developer Story." That means I did something actively to have a CV (which was later migrated), meaning I had to opt in. I want to see that opt-in thingy again.

I don't want to give any reasons about why I'm asking this.

Comment: Let's make this the canonical faq for the issue - I don't see one already existing

Answer (score 3):

First off, let me clarify that the 'Powered by Crunchbase' logo **does not and has never meant** that we share *any* data with Crunchbase. We use Crunchbase data as a source of company information (for the autocomplete) and nothing will **ever** be shared with them. We're not in the business of selling user data and I don't expect that to *ever* be the case.

Now onto your other points:

Developer Story replaces CVs. There is no way to opt out of this - it's a one-way migration and CVs are deprecated. We've maintained the traditional CV view and that's what is seen by employers by default, but all editing is performed using the new timeline view.

The opt-in you saw from Developer Story was a temporary feature for migrating users in the beta with a CV into Developer Story. The email you received was simply a heads up that this was happening and the steps needed to do so.

That said, you can opt out of using your Developer Story being seen by employers by visiting your profile and setting your [job match preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) to 'Not interested in jobs'. This removes you from our candidate search product, but doing so completely removes you from view. You cannot revert to being visible using your legacy CV.

Similarly your [job match preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) control how we match jobs to you in /jobs. Removing all information here means that the matching algorithm no longer has any data to match you to jobs and so will show you things based upon your geo-location and your [Providence](https://kevinmontrose.com/2015/01/27/providence-machine-learning-at-stack-exchange/) data. You can clear that data by managing your [prediction data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data). You can opt out from there too.

If you no longer wish to receive emails about jobs you can opt out of all emails by visiting your [email preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current#job-board) and unchecking all the boxes.

Comment: Thanks! I did what you said and the jobs offered to me are still all strongly Java-related, compared to a new user. Also, my developer story profile still contains data about me which shouldn't be in if I didn't opt-in: Check images [new user](http://i.imgur.com/R01mRPj.png) vs. [existing user](http://i.imgur.com/lof2VgY.png). So I didn't entirely "opt-out" from the feature. In developer story, a new user has none of "actively looking", "open but not looking" and "not interested" checked. An existing user has at least one checked. So no, profile isn't reset to a state without Developer Story.

Comment: Also, the prediction data is useful for me when I use the website, but it's apparently still used when I'm checking the jobs page (hence the strongly java-related jobs I guess). I'd like to disable for the jobs but not for my personal usage of the website main activity, which is the Q&A.

Comment: We don't support doing that right now (and it'd likely be low priority in the backlog). You can not use matches data by using the [newest](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=p) sort instead.